# combined price for wordpress woocommerce products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product

I have 5 products with price

1. product1 - $49.99
2. product2  - $49.99
3. product3  - $49.99
4. product4  - $ 70.00
5. product5  - $70.00

When user buy any single product the price will be same as shown in front of product name above
But

When user buy the product with combination of

product5 & product3 = $99.99

product1, product2 & product5 = $149.99

How can i do this using woocommerce wordpress plugin

Comment: can you post the code of what you tried so far to achieve this?

Comment: [Product Bundles](http://www.woothemes.com/products/product-bundles) or [Dynamic Pricing](http://www.woothemes.com/products/dynamic-pricing/) might be helpful.